# cordova filesystem overwrite string

Tags: cordova, phonegap, filewriter

I'm using [FileWriter](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) to save two strings each to a file seperately. When I manually delete a file, everything works as intended . But as soon as a file exists, FileWriter doesn't properly overwrite.

Code:

```
    $('#buttonExport').click(function () {

    let exportLines = createFeatureCollection(splitLinesArray);
    let exportPoints = JSON.stringify(duplicatedLayer);

    let exportArray = [exportLines,exportPoints];
    let exportNameArray = ['routes.geojson','points.geojson'];

    for (let i =0; i< exportArray.length; i++) {
        try {
            window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 10 * 1024 * 1024, gotFS, failFS);

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error:', e);
        }

        function gotFS(fileSystem) {

            fileSystem.root.getFile(exportNameArray[i], {
                create: true,
                exclusive: false
            }, gotFileEntry, failFS);


        }

        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, failFS);
        }

        function gotFileWriter(writer) {
            //writer.seek(0);
            writer.write(exportArray[i]);

        }

        function failFS(error) {
            console.log(error.code);
        }
    }
});
```

points.geojson after first export (valid):

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"infoText":"","imageName":""},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[17.578125000000004,48.22467264956519]}}
```

points.geojson after second export (invalid, missing string):

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"infoText":"","imageName":""},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[17.578125000000004,48.22467264956519]}},{
```

I've tried resetting the file pointer to the beginning each time with

```
writer.seek(0);
```

and

```
writer.truncate(0);
```

Both didn't have any effect on the behavior. Is there anything wrong with my loop?

Comment: why don't you use a database for this?

Comment: the app has to work completely offline and I haven't found any standalone-db drivers for cordova yet., also the output (*.geojson) has to readable by gis programs

Comment: you can use local websql db. Make a service which writes *.geojson to do db and gets *.geojson from db. I think it will be much easier than writing to and reading from files